# c++ boost gzip in-memory binary compression

Tags: c++, boost, binary, compression, gzip

I am trying to compress a data in an array using boost iostream and gzip, here is my code:

```
struct String_sink  : public boost::iostreams::sink 
{
    std::string& s;
    String_sink(std::string& s):s(s){}
    std::streamsize write(const char* s, std::streamsize n) 
    {
        this->s.append(s, n);
        return n;
    }
};


boost::iostreams::stream< boost::iostreams::array_source > source ((char*)dataBitstream.GetData(), dataBitstream.GetNumberOfBytesUsed());
std::string compressed;
boost::iostreams::filtering_streambuf<boost::iostreams::input> outStream; 
outStream.push(boost::iostreams::gzip_compressor(1)); 
outStream.push(source); 
boost::iostreams::copy(outStream, String_sink(compressed));
```

While this compresses the data, it does it as text. I want it to do it in **binary**. The reason is if I save the "dataBitstream" to a file using the `ios_base::binary` flag, then compress the file using gzip.exe, the result size is 50% smaller then what I get in code. Both cases I'm using "1" as compression level. Without the binary flag, the file does indeed compress to same size as what I see in code.

So anyone have idea how to compress array as binary? So far I've tried using a `std::stringstream::binary` flagged stringstream as input, and creating a sink for stringstream out that calls the `read()` function. This did not work.

Is it possible to force compress an array as binary data??

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at this line:

```
outStream.push(boost::iostreams::gzip_compressor(1));
```

And comparing it to the documentation I Googled pertaining to [Boost's gzip facilities](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/gzip.html).

```
basic_gzip_compressor( const gzip_params& = zlib::default_compression, 
                       std::streamsize buffer_size = default value );
```

So you're specifying a compression value of 1. That's the lowest setting (i.e., least amount of compression). The default value (used in case of a plain gzip.exe command line) is 5. Try using that, or even 9 (not guaranteed to compress much more but might use more time and memory).

I don't think text vs. binary should make a difference in this case.

Comment: I did use compression level "1" in both my code and gzip.exe, and that sadly is not the case. I'm sure saving out the data as binary made a difference. The key was the 'ios_base::binary' flag for the 'ofstream'. However, this binary flag does not work for 'stringstream'.

Comment: What happens if you use 5 or 9 in both situations? Is there still a wide disparity?

Comment: There are some difference between 5 and 9, but not as big as the difference between file type. I even tried reading the binary file back into the code using `ios_base::binary`, and surprisingly it compressed at higher ratio (same as gzip.exe). But I need to do this without having to save to disk.